# In a sequence of words where the "ends" are opposites, what do you call the middle word?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, in the sequence *late - on time - early*, *early* is the **antonym** of *late*, and *delayed* would be a **synonym**. But what about ***on time***, the "neutral" word in the sequence? What is the relationship of *on time* and *early*? Is there a word for this?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean.

Comment: If the word is `delayed`, you call `late` as synonym, `early` as antonym, and `on schedule` is to what?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Let us assume the word is "neutral". What would such a word be for "good". For example, bad(antonym), ?(neutral)

Comment: If you use the word *delayed* as your reference point, then *on schedule* is not "neutral". It's an antonym, too.

Comment: If a word means the same thing, it's a synonym. If it means the opposite, it's an antonym. I don't know what would be "neutral" in such a context. I suppose a word could have a related meaning, like "bottom" is the opposite of "top", what relation is "middle" to "bottom"? It's clearly related, but I don't think we have a word for such relationships.

Comment: @Martha I'm not sure the edit really helped, unless we just drop the last two questions altogether. Because those two are still asking the same thing as previously, and the answer is still the same as before. *On time* and *early* are still antonyms.

Comment: Related question: what do you call such a sequence, where there are two (or 3 ) sets of "antonyms" possible: late/early, late/on time, early/on time. That is, where the "norm" would be simple antonyms like sick/healthy, up/down, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of terms being used in your question. In an attempt to make things a little more clear:

> *antonym* — a word opposite in meaning to another (e.g., bad and good).

The first thing to remember is that "opposite" here does not strictly mean "polar opposite on one particular scale." With regards to *late*, *on-time* and *early* are both antonyms.

The second thing to remember is that antonyms are not logical constructs — they are still linguistic constructs. The implication that two words are antonyms of each other is not inherently wrong but it may muddle the truth a bit. For instance: *early* and *late* are antonyms of *on-time* but it is entirely possible that the inverse is not as true. Is *on-time* really an antonym of *early*? Perhaps, but it causes me some pause.

> *sequence* — a particular order in which related events, movements, or things follow each other

In this case, the sequence is variance between arrival and scheduled arrival. The center of this sequence can be called many things:

- midpoint — the exact middle point
- middle
- halfway point
- midway point
- center
- balance

And so on. Most of these words are used for a more strict definition of sequence or to explain a point between two distances.

In terms of looking at things as a sequence, the term *antonym* drastically shifts meaning since these things are much more logical or mathematical. Specifically, what is *opposite* depends a great deal on the type of sequence being used.

Unfortunately, the more picky one gets about opposites, the less the term *antonym* applies. If two towns are across the river from each other they are *opposite* each other but they are most certainly not *antonyms* of each other.

> *neutral* — having no strongly marked or positive characteristics or features

My dictionary is not doing this word justice, unfortunately. *Neutral*, in your usage, implies the halfway point you described from earlier. But in your example, *on-time* fulfills more of a pinnacle or balancing point:

- fulcrum — a thing that plays a central or essential role in an activity, event, or situation
- accurate

The act of being late or early is *missing* the goal of being on-time. Represented as such, *late* and *early* are antonyms of *on-time* and could be considered opposites of each other in the same sense as the two towns across each other from the river.

Imagine a mathematical tree drawn out with the tip being *on-time* and the two children as *late* and *early*. A line connects *late* and *early* but only by traveling through *on-time*.

---

All of this is to lead into the actual answer to your question:

> What is the relationship of on time and early?

There are two ways to answer this question: One is to look at the relationship between *on-time* and *early* as they exist in a *sequence* and the second is to look at them as potential antonyms.

The difference between them with regards to the sequence is strictly one of numbers: *on-time* would be the goal and *early* is someone not hitting that on the nose.

In regards to them as potential antonyms, one could make the case of them being antonyms of each other.

The question you may have been trying to ask was:

> If *late* and *early* are antonyms, then what is *on-time*?

The answer is that *on-time* is also an antonym.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong picture in your head, namely, a straight line segment in which the antonyms are at the two ends.

The correct picture is that of a circle, with the top point removed, and the two antonyms pulled back just a bit. The “bottom” point is the “neutral” point. Then, whether you are dealing with synonyms or antonyms depends on your point of reference. The “naïve” point of reference is to simply consider the relationships of the surface meanings of the things at about the same hight on the circle, in which case, to use your example, “early” and “late” are antonyms. The “sophisticated” point of reference is to use the neutral (actually, not “neutral” but “desired”) point (at the bottom of the circle) as the point of reference, any and all deviations from which are considered SYNONYMS. That is, being too early or being too late are SYNONYMS in relation to being “on time”.

The case in point concerns time, and my take is that the term “on time” IS the term for the “neutral” / “desired” status between “early” and “late”.

Comment: For the downvoters, any reasons?

Comment: @Mitch: The light hurts their eyes.

Answer (score 0):

In [WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=2&s=antonym&i=2&h=10000#c), these would fall under the more general category of `sister term` but I don't think there is a specific word for the exact relationship described. If you wanted to coin a word, perhaps *mesonym* would work.